# Why is Jesse's car's trunk going up and down in Breaking Bad?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

In the first season of Breaking Bad, we can see Jesse's car's trunk going up and down a few times. Although one of those cases is when Walt and Jesse are locked in the trunk, another time it seems to go up and down on its own?

Is it a mechanical defect of the car?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its not a defect, its for show. Hydraulics are used to make the car bounce. He has a switch that he uses to make it jump.

Here is an article on hw hydaulics work : http://auto.howstuffworks.com/under-the-hood/trends-innovations/question294.htm

Comment: Kids these days...